# How do you highlight TreeViewItem?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a simple treeview with all the default colors.  When you click on an item it is highlighted and the background turns blue.  Fine so far.  I'm trying to do the same thing in the code behind so that I can have a treeview item of my choice highlighted in blue.  The only property I see that I have found that changes the background is ".IsSelected".  But when I set that to true the treeview item is highlighted in white.  I don't get it.  I'm not setting the highlight color to anything so why would it pick a different highlight color than when you select that same item with a mouse click?  Is "highlight" a different property than "select" and if so how what is the name of that property?

Thanks.

Edit: Adding code (My apologies, this was so simple so I didn't think anyone would want to see the code)

Xaml: (and yes, this the entire code. Just plug it into a project and it'll run.)

```
 <Window x:Class="TestTreeView.Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Tree View Icon"
ShowInTaskbar="false"
Name ="MyTestTreeView"
Background="Beige"
Width="500"
Height ="500"
>
<StackPanel Name="stackpanel">
    <Button Name="AddNode" Click="btnClick">
            AddNode
    </Button>

    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="hidden" Name="scrollViewer">
        <TreeView Name="treeView" BorderThickness="0">
            <TreeView.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="Red" x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"/>
            </TreeView.Resources>
        </TreeView>
    </ScrollViewer>
</StackPanel>
```

Code behind:

```
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.IO;
namespace TestTreeView
{
    public partial class Window1 : System.Windows.Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }       
        public void btnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TreeViewItem n1 = new TreeViewItem();
            n1.Header = "Top Node";
            n1.IsSelected = true;
            n1.Focus();
            treeView.Items.Add(n1);          
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your question currently looks like a wall of text with no code. Try to improve it by using proper punctuation and include the relevant code of whatever you're having problems with.

Comment: OK but if I provide the whole code I want a whole answer ;)  Just updated my comment, sorry for the boring description.  And thanks for the welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TreeviewItem.Focus() method would solve your problem. In your code you have missed to set ItemContainerStyle and you have to focus TreeViewItem after adding into the TreeView like below

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="myLBStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Green" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Red" />
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TreeView Name="Treeview1" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource myLBStyle}" />
    <Button Content="Select" Width="300" Height="30" Click="Button_Click_2" />
</Grid>
```

```
TreeViewItem n1 = new TreeViewItem();
n1.Header = "Top Node";
n1.IsSelected = true;

Treeview1.Items.Add(n1);
n1.Focus();
```

Comment: This is addressing how to actually click an item and then see the color change, isn't it?  I'm talking about how to highlight an item in the code behind without mouse-clicking it.  Thank you for your input.

Comment: In above code snippet, there is no interaction with mouse click. Just for the demo purpose i wrote code in button click. The button click uses Focus method to select the item without any mouse interaction. In XAML snippet you can 2 resources defined to reflect color on selection.

Comment: You missed to add ItemContainerStyle for Treeview in your snippet. Please refer my snippet. It's working for me

Comment: Yes.  But as my code above indicates, n1, which is the newly created TreeViewItem, calls n1.Focus(), just like your code suggests.  And it's not doing anything. What am I missing.

Comment: I have updated my answer based on your question. It's working. Please accept the answer

Comment: Aha!  The focus has to be AFTER the add.  You are most excellent, my friend.  Thank you, and answer accepted.

Comment: @Raywan : The answer you accepted is not mine :( . Only one answer you can accept. Please mark the answer as accepted. Thanks

Comment: There we go, Vimal.  I almost gave it to someone else!  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Focus() method of the TreeViewItem.

Comment: I have that in the code above and doesn't do it.  Should that focus call be moved elsewhere or applied to something different?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the most maintainable approach would require you to set the `SelectedItem` or `SelectedValue` on your `TreeView` to be one of the items of interest in your `ItemsSource` for the control. If you are using bindings, this should be very easy to do -- just update the respective property on your ViewModel.

This is what you need to do if you are trying to mimic the user picking an item from your list. Let me know if I am incorrect or if you need more guidance, but we will need more code/examples from you first most likely.

Comment: I have supplied the code above.  Would you mind marking it up with the changes if they're not too extensive?