# XAML: Make TreeViewItem using VS theme colors

Tags: wpf, xaml, colors, visual-studio-2013, treeview

I'm creating a Visual Studio extension with a tool window. There I use a TreeView. I want this tree view to use the current Visual Studio theme. Thanks to the post [How do you highlight TreeViewItem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18901188/how-do-you-highlight-treeviewitem) I was able to set the the Text and Highlight colors. But there are more issues:

- the colors only update on (re-)start of visual studio but not directly when I change the theme
- How to I change the unfocused highlight colors?
- How do I change the expandable icon colors to the current theme colors?
- Any chance to make the highlight go over the full with as it is in the Solution Explorer window?

Here is my current XAML code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="DavidSpeck.CSharpDocOutline.DocOutlineView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.12.0"
         Background="{DynamicResource VsBrush.Window}"
         Foreground="{DynamicResource VsBrush.WindowText}"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
         Name="MyToolWindow">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="CETreeViewItem" TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}" Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static shell:VsColors.ToolWindowTextKey}}" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static shell:VsColors.HighlightKey}}" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static shell:VsColors.HighlightTextKey}}" />
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TreeView Name="outlineTreeView" 
                  Background="{DynamicResource VsBrush.Window}"
                  BorderThickness="0"
                  ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource CETreeViewItem}">
        </TreeView>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```